# How to push new modal right after dismissing current modal in React Native using Wix navigator in iOS?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, react-native, navigation, navigator

I'm using Wix navigator in my iOS app. Is there any callback method when I use this.props.navigator.dismissModal()? If no, how do I open another modal right after dismissing current one?

After I dismiss current modal which is shown using this.props.navigator.showModal(), I would want another modal to be pushed. There is no callback. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onDismiss()` method inside the modal code